# Is it possible for the gradient of an exponential to be the same as a trig function

Tags: calculus, functions

I have an assignment that requires us to make a continuous rollercoaster. we have to find the derivative of the functions we us and show that the gradients match. I have part of my rollercoaster done but I was wondering whether or not you can somehow connect an exponential function to the rollercoaster. Heres what my graph looks like atm.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Some points on an exponential will have the same sloped as a trig function. For example you can easily find points with slope $\frac12$ on both. However most points on an exponential will have slower greater than $1$ which trig functions never achieve.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I am guessing you can multiply your trigonometric functions by a constant

Comment: @Henry Then any function with a non-zero derivative will work and that completely trivializes the problem.

Comment: There is a continuity issue for the derivatives - you will need continuity in distance and in velocity.  Even a discontinuity in acceleration will cause an uncomfortable [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)).